# absolute paths with react-native raise eslint errors

Tags: react-native, absolute-path, eslint

in my React Native app, within my `package.json` I've set the name to `rpms`. This allows me to do:

```
import Component from 'rpms/App/common/Component'
```

Flow gets on well with this type of imports, however eslint-plugin-import raises `import/no-extraneous-dependencies`, and `import/no-unresolved`. I've added to my rules:

```
"import/no-unresolved": [2, { "ignore": ["rpms"] }],
```

And that way I disconnect `import/no-unresolved`. To disable the other I've tried with:

```
"settings": {
  "import/ignore": ["rpms"]
},
```

However it's not working. However, I have the feeling, that maybe ignoring these errors is not the right way to go.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I just started an issue [over on GitHub](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/626).

Comment: No, I'm now following your Github issue, looks like support is missing. However I'm extending airbnb eslint config and it works for them, weird

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Published a package to solve this issue

https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-reactnative

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I opened a PR some days before you proposing to adjust node resolver to handle RN absolute imports, but it was closed in favor of your standalone resolver. https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/pull/638 so I'm accepting this as the answer to the question. I would add a little section in your README on how to set the resolver in eslint settings